# Pandas: select only the first row of a column

Tags: pandas

I have a problem with the pandas dataframe. I have this df:

```
       ID                     type
28030  LVE-188599             PPC
28031  LVE-188599             PPC
28032  LVE-188599             PPC
28033  LVE-188599       Affiliate
28034  LVE-188599             PPC
28035  LVE-188599             PPC
28036  LVE-188599             PPC
```

and I want to select only the unique values of the column "type" inside the same group of ID ( I want to obtain a dataframe with two columns as result):

```
       ID                     type
28030  LVE-188599             PPC
28033  LVE-188599       Affiliate
28034  LVE-188599             PPC
```

Do you know how can I do this? 
I used to work with SAS and this can be easily solved doing a

```
data out;
set in;
by ID;
if first.type;
run;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you recheck you input and output once?

Comment: Your output doesn't match what you are saying. For ID with value `LVE-188599` there are two unique types - PPC and Affiliate. Your result dataframe has PPC twice.

Comment: yes, probably I was not correct when I asked the question... the output is correct, I actually don't need the unique value, I need to eliminate all consecutive equal values of the column "type"

Comment: I got it!    df.loc[(df.id != df.id.shift(1)) | (df.type != df.type.shift(1))]

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[(df.id != df.id.shift(1)) | (df.type != df.type.shift(1))]
```

it works!